# get multiple values database generated drop down from one jsp to other

Tags: java, database, jsp

[Output of drop down getting values from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWjsL.png)

```
<td> 
                Chose Country  : <br><select name ="Country" id="country" size="20"  style="width: 90%;" multiple>
                    <%while (resultset.next()) {%>
                    <option value="<%=resultset.getString(1)%>"><%=resultset.getString(1)%></option>
                    <%}%>           
                </select> 
            </td>
```

//getting values at total jsp but country is same not taking distinct values

```
String country=request.getParameter("Country"); 
        String country1=request.getParameter("Country");
        String country2=request.getParameter("Country"); 
        String country3=request.getParameter("Country"); 
        String country4=request.getParameter("Country"); 
at URL take values fine but how to get them using request.getParameter?
```

[at URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVzWy.png)

Comment: That's a bad style coding. Using your resultSet directly in scriplet tag in JSP. It can welcome security issues.!!

Comment: I am a beginner. its f9 for me for practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getParameterValues()` it returns a String array with all the option selected
like this:

```
String country=request.getParameterValues("Country");
```

Comment: Although as they said it's not recommended to use the result set in the jsp page. Read about JSTL library and EL it's usefull in java ee